# How to remove first index of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following data

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [operations] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [method] => 
POST)))
Array ( [1] => Array ( [operations] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [method] => POST))))
```

I want to dispay like this

```
Array ( [operations] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [method] => POST)))
```

How to i remove the first index of array

I am using the following code but its not work for multiple array

```
$key = array_shift($array);
```

Comment: `$newArray = $yourArray[0];`. Do you mean that.

Comment: Yes,but i have Array ( [0] => Array ( [operations] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [method] => POST)))),Array ( [1] => Array ( [operations] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [method] => POST))))  like this

Comment: Go with a `for-loop` over all like that.

Comment: how are you getting the data. is it from database or what. If you are sure you will always get only one array element. then you can follow what @AjAX. mentioned and use $newArray for any further operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally get what your after.  Try this and see if it gets you what you want:

```
$array =  Array (

  array('0' => Array ( 'operations' => Array ( '0' => Array ( 'method' => POST)))),
  array('1' => Array ( 'operations' => Array ( '0' => Array ( 'method' => POST))))

);

foreach($array as $key=>$value){

$results[$key]['operations'] = $array[$key][$key]['operations'];

}


print_r($results);
```

This will output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [operations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [method] => POST
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [operations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [method] => POST
                        )

                )

        )

)
```